# "HP Smart Install" on inserted pen-drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

Few days ago I bought HP printer for my home network. I connected it via USB into W7 x64 with SP1, and (as it was stated in manual), PC detected this as connected external drive with drivers included. I double clicked it and it begin installation (I have autorun disabled). Once it finished installation, the extern drive disappeared. Few days ago I plug in a pen-drive which got the same drive letter as that external drive had (H:) and after double click I've got error "H:\ Can't locate application" (in polish), and when I right clicked it I've got that rollout:

```
HP Smart Install <- default
Autorun
Open
Open in new window
Share
...
```

(I've captured a screenshot in polish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBUV0.jpg )

I am *absolute sure* there is no *autorun.inf* on pen-drive and the problem also persisted when I connected other external drive which also get the same drive letter (H:).

How can I get rid of that "HP Smart Install"?

Just as side note - I had to install also 32 bit version of drivers on my W7 x64, so the printer is usable by other computers in my home network (especially Win XP x86 one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's strange - few reboots later I've noticed the problem disappear by itself... I guess it has to be some kind of windows cache